# Non-modal wizard in VMWare Clarity and Angular

Tags: angular, vmware-clarity

[Clarity offers an extensive system for creating wizard UI](https://clarity.design/documentation/wizards#top).

Is it possible to have a wizard that is non-modal, not a dialog window, but just sits in the centre of the page? I have a use case for a page that is nothing but the wizard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Stepper](https://clarity.design/documentation/stepper) is the recommended way for inline multi-step forms.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar situation before. I ended up using the Timeline component. Maybe you can try as well. Hope that